# Why does margin-right not work, but margin-left, margin-top and margin-bottom do?

Tags: css, margin

When I set margin-right: 50px; I do not see any effect, yet when I replace the margin-right: 50px; with margin-left: 50px; or margin-top: 50px; I do see an effect. Here is the code with margin-right...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Max Pietsch homepage</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .me {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        #pic_of_me {
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="me">
        <img id="pic_of_me" src="me.jpg" alt="A picture of me">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's... not the code with margin-right.

Comment: What are you expecting margin-right to do?

Comment: Can't see the `margin-right`

Comment: Assuming that you meant to place `margin-right` and not `top` in the above snippet, it does work, but `.me` is a block element, so takes up the entire line. You can see that it works in [this example by adding background colours](https://jsbin.com/fujene/edit?html,css,output). Note what happens when you remove the divs right margin.

Comment: try to fill up some content (long text) and it will work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Html elements are** per default always **alligned at the top left corner of their parent** element.

Your `.me` is thus placed in the top left corner of the `body` element.

If you add a `margin-top` or `margin-left` your `.me` "pushes" itself away from this corner (this is why you see it moving) .

If you add a `margin-right` or `margin-bottom` other elements on the right/below your element would be "pushed" away.

As **you don't have any elements on the right/below your element** you can't see this effect.

Try it out!

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.